# No menus of any type availab

Tags: raspbian, noobs, desktop

How do I open terminal without menu bar?  No menu bar is visible so I can't get there to try anything suggested online.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what exactly the problem is. But if you want to open a fullscreen terminal you can try to press ALT + CTRL + F3 for example. To get back to your Desktop you can press ALT + CTRL + F7

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers to my poorly stated question.  I found a solution.  The problem wasn't the raspberry pi, it was the tv I was connected to via hdmi.  After looking up the term "overscan" I found that overscan could be shut off in the tv menus.  I did so, and now all is okay.  All of the menu items are present.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few more keyboard shortcuts, maybe one of these will help.

System menu: ctrl + esc

Open program menu: alt + space

Switch program: alt + tab

Access dropdown: alt + [letter-with-underline] e.g. alt + f

Close window: ctrl + q

Back to CLI: ctrl + alt + backspace